# Dropbox oauth2/token endpoint not returning refresh_token

Tags: dropbox

I am trying to create a simple app using the dropbox api. My app constructs a URL to request access permissions from the user. I am setting the token_access_type to "offline".
The url looks like this:

.../oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<APP_CODE>&token_access_type=offline

After the user authorizes the app I then send the following data to the oauth2/token endpoint: code = <CODE_FROM_WEBSITE> grant_type = authorization_code client_id = <APP_CODE> client_secret = <APP_SECRET>

The call succeeds, I get an access_token. But there is no refresh_token. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/oauth2-token-endpoint-not-returning-refresh-token/td-p/612640 ]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a saved URL to create the access_token  - and that saved URL had the wrong token_access_type parameter.